# Php Using a Button

Tags: php, html

This is my code :

```
<html>
<form action="employee.php">
Enter Ssn To Delete Employee:<br>
<input type="number" name="ssnDel">
<br>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</html>
```

Inside employee.php , I echo name, lastname etc. of selected employee. I created a button and I want to do some opreations when I click on that button. Here is a part of employee.php

```
<?php
    $ssnDel = $_GET ["ssnDel"];
    $button = "<input type='button' id='php_button' value='Submit' onClick= ''>";

    $sql = "SELECT * from employee WHERE ssn=".$ssnDel;

    // echo operations

    echo $button;

?>
```

My button doesn't do anything. I made some research, some people used Java Script, some used AJAX but I don't have any knowledge on them. Is there a solution which I can use php and html?

Comment: Define "doesn't do anything".  Where do you execute your SQL query?  Where do you examine the results from the database?  What are you expecting it to do?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: @David When someone clicks on that button, I will use DELETE FROM employee where ssn =".$ssnDel; line to delete selected employee.

Comment: Then why don't you do exactly that?  Where are you stuck?  Also, be aware that using the `$ssnDel` value directly in the SQL query like that is a SQL injection vulnerability.  You might want to look into using prepared statements instead.

Comment: @David first, I echo a table on screen to show user which employee has that Ssn number. Then, there will be a submit button again, if user clicks it, that employee will be deleted.

Comment: Are you describing what your code does, or are you describing a set of requirements that you want someone to write the code *for you*?  Again, it's not clear where you're stuck or what the problem is.  Nobody here is going to write all of your code for you.  What have you tried, and what specific problem have you encountered?  If the problem is that you don't know how to receive form input or use a database then the answer is to start with just about any introductory tutorial on PHP.

Comment: @David I don't want anyone to write my code. I already written most of it and I stuck in button part. Right now, my code gets a Ssn number, by using mySql database it show a table with employee whose Ssn number is input. My problem starts here : I want to create a button, when I click on that button, that employee will be deleted. I created $button but onClick part is empty. I tried to create functions but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="employee.php">
```

add a method:

```
<form action="employee.php" method="post">
```

than:

```
$ssnDel = $_POST["ssnDel"];
```

This thing just echo's a button with Submit writen on it, its useless.

```
$button = "<input type='button' id='php_button' value='Submit' onClick= ''>";

echo $button;
```

What do you want to do ? To delete some line from your database ?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete someone. I will use DELETE FROM employee where ssn =".$ssnDel; line . I didn't understand that method part.